# PHP: why would dechex fail even with small number?

Tags: php, binary, hex

I'm having trouble converting a binary string to a hexadecimal string using bindec and dechex functions. In my research I have discovered that either PHP in general or dechex specifically has an integer size limitation of  319259235818.  However, my code fails even the maximum possible integer in my application is an order of magnitude smaller

```
$bin = "11111111111111111111111111111111111";
var_dump($bin); //'11111111111111111111111111111111111' (length=35)

$dec = bindec($bin);
var_dump($dec); // float 34359738367

$hex = dechex($dec);
var_dump($hex); // 'ffffffff' (length=8) (binaryhexconverter.com shows 7FFFFFFFF (length 9) as the result)

$dec2 = hexdec($hex);
var_dump($dec2); //float 4294967295

$bin2 = decbin(hexdec($hex));
var_dump($bin2); //'11111111111111111111111111111111' (length=32)
```

What is going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's clearly said in the [**documentation**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.dechex.php):

> The largest number that can be converted is `PHP_INT_MAX * 2 + 1` (or
>   -1): on 32-bit platforms, this will be `4294967295` in decimal, 
>   which results in `dechex()` returning `ffffffff`.

And it's relatively clear that you're working with 32-bit platform, as [**bindec()**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.bindec.php) produced a `float`, not `integer` in your case:

> The function can convert numbers that are too large **to fit into the
>   platforms integer type**, larger values are returned as float in that
>   case.

The catch is, while `bindec` indeed is 'smart enough' to make such a conversion, `dechex` won't do that - it only works with `integer` values.

Comment: Thanks for the rapid response. Instead of looking around the net, I should have started with the documentation.